# Using "touch" to create directories - create "shadow" copy of directories recursively

Tags: linux, bash

1. In the "A" directory:
   `find . -type f > a.txt`
2. In the "B" directory:
   `cat a.txt | while read FILENAMES; do touch "$FILENAMES"; done`

Result: Step 2 "creates the files" (I mean only with the same filename, but with 0 Byte size) but if there are subdirs in the "A" directory, then step 2 can't create the files in the subdir, because there are no directories in it.

Question: Is there a way, that "touch" can create directories?

Comment: Cross-posted on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/234185/using-touch-to-create-directories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the original, "A" directory:

```
find . -type f > a.txt
```

"B" directory:

```
while read file; do if [[ "$file" = */* ]]; then mkdir -p "${file%/*}"; fi; touch "$file"; done < a.txt
```

Answer (score 8):

quick shot:

```
while read FILENAME
do
  mkdir -p $(dirname "$FILENAME") && touch "$FILENAME"
done < a.txt
```

Be aware of special chars (whitespaces, ...) in file-/pathnames and so on ...

Comment: then you also want double-quotes around the $(...) substitution, to protect against whitespace-splitting of the result, and should figure out how to deal with newlines embedded in the filenames.  find's -print0 and using a shell which supports having read use a NUL delimiter may help.

Comment: Phil P is right, you can put quotes around the `$(..)`, even if it contains quotes itself (as in this case) and Bash will do The Right Thing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on quite a [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) kick lately.  Here's a way to do this in one line using that tool:

```
find A -type d | parallel 'mkdir -p B/$(dirname {})' && find . -type f | parallel 'touch B/{}'
```

Note that this is inefficient because it runs a lot of extra unneeded `mkdir -p` for intermediary directories. That should be optimized if you are dealing with really huge directory structures.

Answer (score 1):

This works even if A contains the file:

A/My brother's 12" records dir/My brother's 12" records

```
(cd A; find . -type f) | (cd B; parallel 'mkdir -p {//}; touch {}')
```

Having dealt with users creating "creative" filenames I always test script like these on

```
My brother's 12" records
```

If it works for that, then chances are good it will not fail.

Thanks to Phil H for giving the basic building blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing:

```
cat a.txt | while read FILENAMES; do touch "$FILENAMES"; done
```

do:

```
cat a.txt | sed -e `s|/[^/]*$||` | uniq | while read DIRNAMES; do mkdir -p "$DIRNAMES"; done
```

As already pointed out, be careful about special char in dirnames/filenames, especially slashes (I would hate to have a file named "aaa/ccc", but it is always possible).